# scala: return value for a method and end the method prematurely

Tags: scala

I am just beginning Scala, so bear with me.

I am writing a method that returns boolean based on the number of "*" found in a given list.

```
def stars(n: Int, chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {
  var count = 0
  chars.foreach{ letter =>
    if (letter == "*") {
      count += 1
    }
    if (count == n) {
      return true
    }

  }
  false
}                                               //> stars: (n: Int, chars: List[Char])Boolean

stars(5, "******".toList)                       //> res12: Boolean = false
```

That should've returned true. Because it should've ended prematurely when the count becomes 5, which becomes equal to `n`.

What am I doing wrong?

Doesn't scala allow ending a method prematurely with `return` statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `if (letter == "*")` you are comparing char with string and thus constantly getting false and your `count += 1` is never evaluated
You have to write `if (letter == '*')` instead

Actually, much more idiomatic code would be:

```
def stars(n: Int, chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {
  n == chars.count(c => c == '*')
}
```

Comment: Your idiomatic code doesn't terminate early.  `chars.iterator.filter(_ == '*').take(5).length == 5` does.